# Sliding view is shifted up a little bit, despite constraints and other settings in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've made a simple one-screen app, that has a custom LadderView on the left side of the screen, TableView on the right side and a sliding ChartView, that lies underneath the LadderView and can be dragged to be shown over the TableView.

**The setup code in the ChartView is something like this:**

```
func setup () {
    let screenHeight = self.superview!.frame.size.height
    let screenWidth = self.superview!.frame.size.width

    self.panGestureReconizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GraphCentreView.handlePan(_:)))
    panGestureReconizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureReconizer)

    self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.superview!)

    self.dynamicItem = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [self])
    self.dynamicItem.allowsRotation = false
    self.dynamicItem.elasticity = 0

    snap = UISnapBehavior(item: self, snapToPoint: CGPoint(x: -screenWidth + 80, y: screenHeight / 2))
    animator.addBehavior(snap)

    self.gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self])
    self.gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(-5, 0)

    self.container = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self])
    self.container.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("leftmost", fromPoint: CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width + 80, 0), toPoint: CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width + 80, screenHeight))
    container.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("rightmost", fromPoint: CGPointMake(screenWidth, 0), toPoint: CGPointMake(screenWidth, screenHeight))

    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
    animator.addBehavior(dynamicItem)
    animator.addBehavior(container)
}
```

The constraints for the ChartView are set to snap to both top and bottom layout guides of the superView. Problem is, though, that the ChartView is shifted a little bit up. I've gone through my code a thousand times, but I can't find anything that would mess with the y coordinate of the GraphView. When I don't add the behaviors to the animator, however, the view is placed just fine, according to the constraints. Could you help me find the problem?

You can see the space between the TabBar and the blurred sliding GraphView.
[image]

Comment: Sorry this is not enough information to provide you an answer. Please share more information. But it seems like that you could fix your problem with a better view-separation to me. You should probably think about multiple view controllers.

Comment: What kind of other information would you need? When I have multiple ViewControllers, though, the ChartVIew's blur won't blur the TableView, because TableView will be in a subcontroller.

Comment: Looks like to few code for that kind of layout. So probably more layout information for an layout issue. You can have multiple view controllers and that blur effects. You can embed them in container views. so you would have many separated view controllers and just one view controller with the container views. You will have to write some code to exchange data between the view controllers but that will make your code much cleaner. And from my experience layout a lot easier.

Comment: Well, that's it for layout though, the rest is only in the constraints. Is there any guide, that would explain what is the right approach here? I'm sure there are some guidelines that would say "if you have 3+ views, it is advised to do ...", I just can't find them. I'd love to choose the most clean and elegant way.

Comment: I don't know any official or well known guide. But from my experience in iOS (4 years iOS-development) I came to the point where I added a rule for me. "Never use a table view, collection view etc… always use the view controller version in combination with container views e.g. a UITableViewController instead of a UITableView" (Of course there can be exceptions but just very few)

Comment: Great, I'll try to stick to containers then. So, when I'll have the left LadderView and right TableView both in containers and over them the sliding GraphView (in the superview of the containers), will they be blurred?

Comment: Yes, if you use a transparent background color.